# how to add likes of an object for the given user

Tags: django, django-views, django-orm

I have a model for forum. There I have a field for question, body, pub_date, image, creator, likes. From the admin, I can add the likes for a given user for a particular forum. But i'm confused all now, how to add likes for the request.user in the views?

models.py:

```
class Forum(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="creator_set")
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Like")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

class Like(models.Model):
    forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum)
    liked = models.ForeignKey(User)
    liked_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s likes %s" % (self.liked, self.forum)
```

I thought of doing like this:

```
>>>forum = Forum.objects.get(id=1)
>>>user = request.user
>>>user.like_set.add(forum)
```

But, it didn't help. Please, any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to [create a URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example) that targets the view. The URL would pass a `forum_id` as a URL parameter.

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required
def update_likes(request, forum_id):
    forum = get_object_or_404(Forum, id=forum_id)
    like, _ = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, forum=forum, 
                   defaults={'liked_date': datetime.now()})
    #rest of the code here.
```

This is one way. You could also do it in the way you thought of doing it, but you will have to manually control the duplicates that could get generated. (you could specify a [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) on the `('forum', 'liked')` )

and to delete

```
@login_required
def delete_likes(request, forum_id):
    forum = get_object_or_404(Forum, id=forum_id)
    like = get_object_or_404(Like, user=request.user, forum=forum)
    like.delete()
    #rest of the code here.
```

Comment: Thanks, I wll try this, and how to delete the likes if the request.user is allready in forum.like_set.all(). Please guide me here.

Comment: Can you please show me what to do in the templates also. I tried request.user, but its telling me anonymous even if Iam logged in.

Comment: just add the decorator `login_required` . It should work fine

Comment: It is `get_or_create` not `get_object_or_create` - I think you are getting confused between that and `get_object_or_404`